# IOS image sizes for buttons

Tags: ios, xcode

I've read the human interface guidelines provided by apple.

Navigation Bar and Toolbar Icon Size:

Target size : 
             72px × 72px (24pt × 24pt @3x)
             48px × 48px (24pt × 24pt @2x)

Max size: 
             84px × 84px (28pt × 28pt @3x)
             56px × 56px (28pt × 28pt @2x)

Does this apply to **regular** buttons as well?

I have a few **regular** buttons with images inside them that are set to Max size (above) but I find its still to small.

Can I change the size to anything I see fit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are guidelines not rules, go crazy with it.

Answer (score 1):

No. You can choose whatever size you want, just make sure the button or other elements are within `safeAreaLayoutGuide`.

Besides, the guidelines are just **Guidelines** , they guide you as to what might look most appropriate as per apple, but these are not necessarily restrictions that **must** be enforced.